# Set content disposition header with files collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, http-headers

I am wondering if it's possible to set value of the `Content-Disposition` header for a user-downloaded file when serving files in meteor application with [files-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection) package.